# Using inline CKEditor on dynamically added text

Tags: ckeditor

I am building a web app that uses javascript to dynamically add elements to the page, that can then be edited using `contentEditable="true"` and `CKEditor`.

Currently if I add an element to the page with `contentEditable="true"`, the element is editable but the `CKEditor` toolbar is not appearing.

I have tried calling `CKEDITOR.inlineAll()` but this doesn't seem to do anything.

How can I activate `CKEditor` inline editing on dynamically created elements? (Without refreshing the page).

EDIT: I have found that giving the element an ID of (e.g.) someId and calling CKEDITOR.inline(someId) has the desired effect. But I don't want to have to add unique IDs to all of my elements. Is there a way to activate CKEditor on all contentEditable elements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`CKEDITOR.inline`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-inline) accepts a native DOM element as a parameter. No matter how you create dynamic elements, if you pass a reference to that function, it will convert it into CKEditor instance. For example, assuming that you use jQuery as a main framework:

```
// A dynamically created element.
var el = $( '<p contenteditable="true">I\'m editable!</p>' );

// Append the element to <body>.
$( 'body' ).append( el );

// CKEDITOR.inline accepts DOM element as parameter.
CKEDITOR.inline( el.get( 0 ) );
```

See [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RKPYw/).

Comment: I have the same problem. calling CKEDITOR.inline(myElement) does change the style of the div, and overrides right click menu, so it almost works, but the menu still doesn't show. Perhaps it has something to do with it being created by knockout..

Comment: another solution could be 

// A dynamically created element.
var html =  '<div id="elementToadd" contenteditable="true">....more html elements...<p>I\'m editable!</p></div>';

// Append the element to <body>.
$( 'body' ).append( html  );
CKEDITOR.inline( 'elementToadd' );

Comment: but how do you get it to immediately activate the ckeditor after inline is finished creating it?