# CKEDITOR freez the screen when applied to dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I was searching for a way to use CKEDITOR inline editor on dynamic created elements so I found this answer here : [Using inline CKEditor on dynamically added text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616119/using-inline-ckeditor-on-dynamically-added-text)

This is how it works

```
<button type="button" onclick="appendEditor()">Append the new editor</button>
```

JS

```
function appendEditor() {
    // A dynamically created element.
    var el = $( '<p contenteditable="true">I\'m editable!</p>' );

    // Append the element to <body>.
    $( 'body' ).append( el );

    // CKEDITOR.inline accepts DOM element as parameter.
    CKEDITOR.inline( el.get( 0 ) );    
}
```

It works like that but every time the text is appended, the screen is frozen for a while (a few seconds), then only after that you can click the text and edit it... It feels like CKEDITOR is blocking all things when it initialize the element given in the parameter `CKEDITOR.inline( el.get( 0 ) )`

How I can solve that ?